# Plugin System in Spring Boot for modular applications

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I looking for dynamically loading jar in spring boot after compiling, for example I will put jars in some folder and when spring boot is started, all jars from this folder will be injected into spring boot app. I don't know how can I do this with spring boot, and if You know can help me with this, with some example.

I need this jars to have @Service, @Controller as this will be module (plugin), with adding capabilities to my spring boot app.

Is possible to do this with spring boot, and if it is possible, please provide me with some sample code.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
I found something https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-sw2pFdcDw https://code.google.com/p/jspf/

UPDATE 2: I can't get @Controller bean from plugin jar registered in Spring Boot

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [FlexiCore](https://github.com/wizzdi/FlexiCore), an open-source framework that brings modularity to spring boot utilizing plugins(jars) loaded at runtime See [wizzdi](https://wizzdi.com) and FlexiCore.
for example FlexiCore allows you to create a project ( compiled into a seperate jar from your main application) that contains a spring bean as follows:

```
@Component
@Extension
public class HelloWorldService implements ServicePlugin{

 public String hello() {
  return "Hello World!";
 }

}
```

it will be automatically be loaded once placed inside the designated plugins folder, it basically allows a full support for most(all) of spring boot features , so for example you can add a RestController bean to your jar as well , FlexiCore will automatically load that bean allowing you to call the controller as if it was in your main application jar:

```
@RestController
@Extension
public class TestEntityController implements Plugin {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityService testEntityService;

    @PostMapping("/createTestEntity")
    public TestEntity createTestEntity(@RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="Stranger") String name) {
        return testEntityService.createTestEntity(name);
    }

    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public TestEntity getTestEntity(@PathVariable("id")String id) {
        return testEntityService.getTestEntity(id);
    }

}
```

Disclaimer: I am the CTO of wizzdi, the company powering FlexiCore.

Answer (score 1):

One option is definitely to just use broad `@ComponentScan`. If you add new jar to `classpath` the annotated classes from that jar will get discovered via `@ComponentScan`, `@Controller`s will get mapped etc.

The XML equivalent here would be placing `xml` configuration files somewhere to your classpath (`META-INF` folder being obvious choice) and import them all using wildcard. The idea is the same. If the plugin jar file is on classpath you will get the `xml` file imported and the beans (controllers, ...) will get loaded.

There are drawbacks to this approach like the modules not being isolated but its definitely option for simpler applications.

Comment: I solved this with jspf from google/code. Than register beans at runtime. In this way i can have jars in some folder, for example plugin enabled or disabled. Just copy/delete...

Comment: @JanZyka Could you provide any examples of how to broad ComponentScan?

Comment: @rvit34: @ComponentScan annotation has basePackage attribute which defaults to _current_ package. If you do for example `@ComponentScan("com")` it will scan all packages starting with `com` and all subpackages regardless of the location of configuration class with the @ComponentScan annotation

Answer (score 0):

You can find a sample spring boot web project [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/).

By dynamically loading jars I assume you want to add dependencies to your project. For this you can update pom.xml of the sample project and put your dependencies here.

Comment: No, no, no... i know that i can add using maven or gradle... I asking something like Spring Dynamic Modules but for Spring Boot. I want to add jar to folder for example "plugins" and after that Spring Boot app will use it.