# Spring Boot 2 with Gradle - Building/Compiling different editions (Basic, Pro, Ultimate) from a single codebase

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, build-tools

**Project Details**

I have a spring boot 2 project with Gradle as the build tool. I'm using Java 8 as the java version. Thymeleaf for the template engine.

**My Goal**

I want to build different editions like Base version, Pro version and Ultimate version. As an example let's say the Base version has 5 features. The Pro version has all the features of the Base version with additional 5 features. And the Ultimate version has all the features of the Pro version with additional 5 features.

**Solutions I have thought of And internet searched solutions**

1. *Keep different branches for different editions*. But here the problem is how to actually manage the codebase, patching fixes, and bringing new features etc. I have also searched for this approach but all are saying not to use this as this is not a good option.
2. *Using Gradle to build multiple editions.* I know in Android there is a features to build multiple flavors of the application like for development, QA, and production. Is there any features for Spring boot that can be utilized to make the editions.
3. *Using some sort of configuration.* we can have a configuration file based on that we can toggle on/off features based on edition. But this can be easily hacked. So I don't dare to use it.
4. *Using Licensing.* This is same as point 3 but slightly different.
5. *Using module features of java (Obviously then I have to upgrade my java version) with some Gradle configuration.* At building time we can include modules based on the

So How do I create different editions ? What is the best solution to make different editions in this scenario where every edition shares some common features with their predecessor edition ?

Please consider that I want to have a single codebase. So that making bug-fixes would be easy as they share some common code/features.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you could do using dependencies and Java's SPI...

You could define a provider interface in some core module (here I called it ":core")

```
package com.example;

interface FlavorProvider {

    String getFlavor();

}
```

Then define an implementation of this in a `basic` module:

```
package com.example;

public class BasicFlavorProvider implements FlavorProvider {

    @Override
    public String getFlavor() {
        return "BASIC!";
    }

}
```

along with a file `resources/META-INF/services/com.example.FlavorProvider` containing the line `com.example.BasicFlavorProvider`

And another in a `pro` module

```
package com.example;

public class ProFlavorProvider implements FlavorProvider {

    @Override
    public String getFlavor() {
        return "PRO!";
    }
}
```

along with a file `resources/META-INF/services/com.example.FlavorProvider` containing the line `com.example.ProFlavorProvider`

Then in your application, optionally include either module as a dependency based on a project property:

```
    implementation(project(":core"))
    if (project.hasProperty("pro")) {
        implementation(project(":pro"))
    } else {
        implementation(project(":basic"))
    }
```

And in your main class you can do:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.ServiceLoader;

public class Main {

    private final ServiceLoader<FlavorProvider> provider = ServiceLoader.load(FlavorProvider.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().run();
    }

    private void run() {
        provider.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.getFlavor()));
    }
}
```

Then:

```
➜ ./gradlew app:run

> Task :app:run
BASIC!
```

And:

```
➜ ./gradlew app:run -Ppro

> Task :app:run
PRO!
```

YMMV, and this doesn't take Spring into account

Comment: I have two concerns with this solutions. 
1. This solution actually includes all the source code into the final build. Though I can use obfuscation. But still is this easily hackable ? Because only a String change would unlock the pro version.
2. If this solution includes every feature into the final build, then shall I have to use toggle (show / hide) the features based on the editions ?

Comment: 1. The basic app doesn't have the pro jar bundled with it. 2. I guess this is answered by 1.  There are probably many other ways of doing the same thing, and you're probably going to need obfuscation anyway.  And licensing.

Comment: It's clear to me now thanks @tim_yates. I'm already searching for Java SPI integration example with Spring boot. But I'm not able to get any useful resources till now. If you have any please share with me. I'm just concern about how to include Base (core in your example) edition into the upper editions (pro here) ? How the Controllers and URL endpoints will work. How the context will work. Thanks again for your support.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25751988/plugin-system-in-spring-boot-for-modular-applications seems a similar question